# How to run an SSH server on a laptop?

Tags: ssh, sleep, launchd, daemon

I want to create a program that allows a user to SSH into their laptop. But there is a serious problem: laptops sleep when they close. In particular, I believe this cannot be disabled on OS X. Does this mean that SSH connections are simply impossible when the laptop is closed? Or is there a way around this?

Comment: -1  for believing that you cannot prevent osx from sleeping when it's closed, that'd be absurd, and that wrong assumption means the answer is more about preventing the laptop from going to sleep that specifically ssh, despite the ssh in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/projects/insomniaxinfo/) is the app you are looking for.